# Speed of WAL send/receive when replicating

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

**1/ Description:**

I have a cluster include two machines

- Master: postgresql 9.3 run on Centos
- Slave : postgresql 9.3 run on Centos

Master ----> Slave : relpica from Master to Slave by asynchronous method (M send WAL, S receive WAL)

**2/ Question:**

How can I monitor (catch) speed of WAL (ex: 1MB/s) is sent from Master to Slave ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pg_stat_replication` along with `pg_xlog_location_diff`. Checking the differences can tell you how many bytes of xlog have flown from the master to the slave.

Comment: Thanks ! I found a script on http://jmorano.moretrix.com/2013/08/postgresql-9-2-master-slave-monitoring/ using pg_xlog_location_diff to monitor latency of bytes between master and slave.

Answer (score 0):

I am using **nethogs** command to tracking WAL send/receive between master and slave.

Download: [nethogs for centos link](http://pkgs.org/centos-6/epel-x86_64/nethogs-0.8.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html)

Install:  `rpm -ivh nethogs-0.8.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`

Tracking: `nethogs eth0`

Ref: [18 commands to monitor network bandwidth on Linux server](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-monitor-network/)